# Program to Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius

Tags: c

I'm trying to convert temperature given in Fahrenheit to Celsius. But for some reason its not working properly. I know that a similar question has been asked but my problem is different because I can't even printout what I have scanned (using scanf) from the user.

*Code:*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
 float Fahrenheit, Celsius;

 clrscr();

 printf("Enter Temperature in Fahrenheit \n");
 scanf("%f",&Fahrenheit);

 Celsius = 5.0/9.0 * (Fahrenheit-32);

 printf("\n Temperature in Fahrenheit = %f", Fahrenheit);
 printf("\n Temperature in Celsius = %f", Celsius);

 getch();
}
```

*Output :*

[image]

I'm using Windows 7 - 64 bit. IDE = Emulated C++ 3.0

Comment: About the only thing that could go wrong is that you do not check the return status from `scanf()` to ensure it succeeded in converting the string.  Strictly, you should use `int main(void)` rather than `void main()`, but that is unlikely to affect the code inside the function.

Comment: It operates properly for me compiled using GCC.

Comment: FYI, This works as intended in linux/g++. Only thing I can see is maybe your compiler loses its mind with `(Fahrenheit-32)` ... try 32.0 but I can't really see that being the issue.

Comment: @ 0x5f3759df, Brian - Thanks for compiling it :)

Comment: your code looks fine (under Visual studio 10). maybe it is some compilerr issue, you could try using fgets() then atof() as a workaround if you don't need to use scanf for your assignment.

Comment: @Anders - Thank you and yes it was a compiler issue. See my comment on quasiverse's answer

Comment: Since you fixed the problem yourself, answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a compiler issue. My compiler (Emulated Turbo C++ 3.0) was not able to save my edits properly. So I went to C:\TC\Bin\ filename.c and opened the file in Notepad. Corrected the errors and compiled it again.

Now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure (because your compiler might behave differently) but perhaps it's caused by this:

You're using `5.0` and `9.0` which are `double` values as well as `32` which is an `int`.

Try changing them to `5.0f`, `9.0f` and `32.0f`.

Comment: I fixed it, my compiler for some reason was not saving the code correctly. I went to C:\TC\Bin\filename.c and opened the file in notepad Corrected the errors then compiled the program again. Now it works fine :)